# Determine the singularity at infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I'm wondering why the function
$$
\frac{z(z^2-\pi^2)}{\sin(z)}
$$
has a nonisolated singularity at infinity? I can identify the singularities which are removable or simple poles here, but sometimes I'm confused with how to discuss the case at infinity.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $\infty$ is not an isolated singularity, since every natural number greater than $1$ is a singularity too.

Comment: Thanks, but if the natural number is infinitely large, and if we consider a disk centered at infinity with a radius less than 1 (say 0.5), then is that still non-isolated?

Comment: There is no such thing as a disk centered at $\infty$ with radius $1$. If an analytic function has a singularity at $\infty$, then $\infty$ is an isolated singularity if, for some $R>0$, there is no singularity in $\{z\in\Bbb C\mid|z|>R\}$.

Comment: Thanks so much:)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.